# Android dev: stream audio via http

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

I want stream live audio via HTTP.

Even though I use prepareAsync() from class MediaPlayer, it takes between 5 and 90 seconds before I horn sound.

Is there a solution for this problem?

I'am developing in Xamarin C#

Comment: That's normal. I don't know about using it with Xamarin, but the external library replacement for Android's media player, called "ExoPlayer" solves all these issues.